# Getting namespace error while adding service reference of 1 wcf service in another wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

I am having 2 wcf services as separate project:

1) RegionService

2) CountryService

**Project name =** **RegionService**

```
IRegionService.cs
IRegionService.svc
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="RegionService.RegionService" CodeBehind="RegionService.svc.cs" %>
```

**Project name =** **CountryService**

```
ICountryService.cs
CountryService.svc
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="CountryService.CountryService" CodeBehind="CountryService.svc.cs" %>
```

Now I would like to consume methods of Region service from Country Service so I have give service reference of RegionService in my CountryService wcf project but when I build the project I get error:

> The type name 'ServiceReference1' does not exist in the type
>   'CountryService.CountryService'

I guess this is happening because of conflicting project name and svc file name as because previously when my svc file name was different from project name I was able to add service reference successfully.

[image]

So is there any workaround for this? I don't want to change name of my files or project as this would lead to changes at lots of places.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

When you add `ServiceReference` change default namespace `ServiceReference1` to something else like `CountryReference` to fix conflict namespace problem.

you are using `ServiceReference1` as namespace for both services

Comment: try delete reference classes, add `servicereference` again with a new namespace , clean & rebuild

Comment: Upvoted for your kind efforts towards helping me and thank you so much for helping me.See my answer how i manage to solved this issue

Answer (score 0):

After a bit research i came up to this below workaround which worked successfully :

```
using AliasCountryService = global::CountryService.ServiceReference1;
```

So now i have replace all `CountryService.ServiceReference1` with `AliasCountryService` which solved my issue.